código de recursividad
estoy usando el lenguaje de programacion pseint, en ella quise intentar lo siguiente, que un codigo con recursividad pueda mostrarme la lista de numeros de la serie fibonacci, pero este codigo me da demasiados errores, aca les paso el codigo que hice, y luego les dire cuales son los errores
Algoritmo practica_1
    Definir n Como Entero;
    escribir "ingrese el número de términos de la serie Fibonacci caballero:"
    leer n;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        escribir Fibonacci(i)
    Fin Para
FinAlgoritmo

SubAlgoritmo Fibonacci(n) Como Entero
    Si n = 0 Entonces
        Fibonacci <- 0
    Sino
        Si n = 1 Entonces
            Fibonacci <- 1
        Sino
            Fibonacci <- Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)
        FinSi
    FinSi
FinSubAlgoritmo

el problema son en estas lineas de codigo
Escribir Fibonacci(i) -> me dice "el subproceso (FIBONACCI) no devuelve ningun valor"
SubAlgoritmo Fibonacci(n) Como Entero -> aca me dice "se esperaba fin de linea"
Fibonacci <- 0
Fibonacci <- 1
Fibonacci <- Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2) en estas tres "identificador no valido (FIBONACCI)
que estoy haciendo tan mal aca? porfavor necesito ayuda
